# File Name for Image Using URL Variable PHP

Tags: php

I found this script, and I want to have the name of the image when downloaded to be the same as the URL Variable. Is that possible? If so, how would one do that? The script I have is...

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="EDITTHIS"');
echo file_get_contents("http://domain.tld/folder/" . $_GET["m"] . ".png");
?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$_GET["m"].'.png"');
echo file_get_contents("http://domain.tld/folder/" . $_GET["m"] . ".png");
?>
```

This assumes `$_GET['m']` is a valid file on your system AND that it is also a png. But, this is basically what you asked for. That EDITTHIS portion of your example is a placeholder, meaning you can name the file whatever you want. Just replace EDITTHIS with anything. In this case, `$_GET['m']`